# Even and primes puzzle?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, primes

These are secret numbers that increase regularly. What are the next two numbers?
If you like numbers, it will be fun.

1. $2^3 \times224299$
2. $2^2 \times 3^2 \times 19 \times 3557$
3. $2 \times 5 \times 320647$
4. $2 \times 599 \times 3011$
5. $2 \times 29 \times 64283$
6. $2^3 \times 7 \times 11^3 \times 59$
7. $2^3 \times 7 \times 47 \times 1877$
8. $2^8 \times 19 \times 1229$
9. $2^2 \times 1639271$
10. $2^3 \times 17 \times 109 \times 569$
11. $2^3 \times 5^3 \times 17 \times 503$
12. $2^4 \times 3 \times 17 \times 29 \times 383$
13. $2^3 \times 233 \times 5051$
14. $2 \times 41 \times 127373$
15. $2^2 \times 3^3 \times 101141$
16. $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7^2 \times 7541$
17. $2^2 \times 3^3 \times 107621$
18. $2^4 \times 746723$
19. $2 \times 3 \times 2051923$
20. $2^2 \times 3 \times 11 \times 94433$
21. $2 \times 139 \times 46061$
22. $2 \times 83 \times 81847$
23. $2^2 \times 37 \times 99233$
24. $2 \times 5 \times 1522067$
25. $2^4 \times 1022963$
26. ??
27. ??

$26^{th}$ and $27^{th}$ number  ?

Comment: Can we be guaranteed that the factorization into primes isn't a red herring? That their actual products can safely be ignored?

Comment: yes it can be ignored, but it will certainly be an even number.